# Azure REST API : oAuth2 authentication granted but invalid token on request

Tags: rest, api, azure, push, guzzle

I have a question about authenticating to azure mobile management API, to send push informations to the API.

I well manage to authentify and receive a token bearer matching to the provided data (tenant id, client id, client secret...), but when I try to create a campaign, I receive the following response :

> ```
> [2016-10-25 11:45:51] (::1) fail to send send request https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/fb8226dc-194f-4562-9dc9-c72f56bd728a/resourcegroups/MobileEngagement/providers/Microsoft.MobileEngagement/appcollections/XX-Collection/apps/XX-TEST-android/campaigns/announcements?api-version=2014-12-01
> ```
>
> with {"name":"The Evian Championship 20... - 25/10/2016
>   11:45:50","type":"only_notif","deliveryTime":"any","pushMode":"one-shot","notificationTickerIcon":true,"notificationIcon":true,"notificationCloseable":true,"notificationSound":true,"notificationVibrate":false,"notificationTitle":"Soci\u00e9t\u00e9
>   G\u00e9n\u00e9rale","notificationMessage":"The Evian Championship
>   2016","actionUrl":"://webviews/main/build/events.html","notificationType":"system"}
>   | "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>       Cache-Control: no-cache
>       Pragma: no-cache
>       Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>       Expires: -1
>       x-ms-failure-cause: gateway
>       x-ms-request-id: 40e30675-2144-452a-9ab9-632a393d8783
>       x-ms-correlation-request-id: 40e30675-2144-452a-9ab9-632a393d8783
>       x-ms-routing-request-id: WESTEUROPE:20161025T094550Z:40e30675-2144-452a-9ab9-632a393d8783
>       Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
>       Date: Tue, 25 Oct 2016 09:45:49 GMT
>       Connection: close
>       Content-Length: 281
>       {"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"The received access token is not valid: at least one of the claims 'puid'
>   or 'altsecid' or 'oid' should be present. If you are accessing as
>   application please make sure service principal is properly created in
>   the tenant."}}" was returned

Here's the request :

> POST
>   /subscriptions/fb8226dc-194f-4562-9dc9-c72f56bd728a/resourcegroups/MobileEngagement/providers/Microsoft.MobileEngagement/appcollections/XX-Collection/apps/XX-TEST-android/campaigns/announcements?api-version=2014-12-01
>   HTTP/1.1 Host: management.azure.com Authorization: bearer
>   eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ikk2b0J3NFZ6QkhPcWxlR3JWMkFKZEE1RW1YYyIsImtpZCI6Ikk2b0J3NFZ6QkhPcWxlR3JWMkFKZEE1RW1YYyJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL21hbmFnZW1lbnQuYXp1cmUuY29tLyIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vc3RzLndpbmRvd3MubmV0LzRmNGFkYjA3LWU5OWQtNDg5NC04OGZjLTZkYzc4ODAzNDI3Zi8iLCJpYXQiOjE0NzczOTUxNzEsIm5iZiI6MTQ3NzM5NTE3MSwiZXhwIjoxNDc3Mzk5MDcxLCJhcHBpZCI6IjUzNzMyOTAwLTU2NGMtNGI2OS1hNGRhLTU0OTQ0ODVkYTFhNiIsImFwcGlkYWNyIjoiMSIsImlkcCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vc3RzLndpbmRvd3MubmV0LzRmNGFkYjA3LWU5OWQtNDg5NC04OGZjLTZkYzc4ODAzNDI3Zi8iLCJ0aWQiOiI0ZjRhZGIwNy1lOTlkLTQ4OTQtODhmYy02ZGM3ODgwMzQyN2YiLCJ2ZXIiOiIxLjAifQ.WvWXETt9IFy_eX2Q8LlguTec9KA2TLgILUs10QULNMYgf1sHUpXdnRhDBqq5Foo_gwF_u2zl1NNYRLmdN3Q0IR3LPspiutAhC_KXvGXmJH2TtxTi9U2bt1Zvf5BsafHkxDdlDG6vymu-3O4cK9HQMu7l0XtPqzcEHcQny94xAq66_TSNa3FhZclwEBnaTI81B5g9NzvET10C0j8ZW0OsRNzc0-czS8RqtXulp1rkIEQc7VhTTDx9feSPi3BJlyhiKxUzfnEn8xUkfqlUEQuqyerqUoRIlbFvhhOT7Gjo6_WJN21Wn-23gcEchaRETWzYh-nTJSeKFzwA-mROOdmUzw
>   User-Agent: Guzzle/5.3.1 curl/7.50.0 PHP/5.6.25 Content-Length: 455

(note : I changed some characters in this displayed bearer by security reasons)

The (real) bearer was obtained requesting https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/token, using this body :

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET}&resource=https://management.azure.com/

Would you have an idea about the reason why the API returned this message ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score -1):

> The received access token is not valid: at least one of the claims 'puid' or 'altsecid' or 'oid' should be present. If you are accessing as application please make sure service principal is properly created in the tenant

It seems that your access token is not valid. I would suggest you follow with [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-engagement-api-authentication/) to get a new token then try again.